# Optimize MySQL database query

Tags: php, mysql

I had a commenting application in my web site. The comments will store in a MySQL table . table structure as follows

```
id   |  Comment    |  user   |   created_date
------------------------------------------------------
12   |  comment he |  1245   |   2012-03-30 12:15:00
------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to run a query for listing all the comments after a specific time. ie .. a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE created_date > "2012-03-29 12:15:00" ORDER BY created_date DESC
```

Its working fine.. My question is if I got a 1-2 lakh entry in this table is this query is sufficient for the purpose ? or this query will take time to execute ? 
In most cases I have to show last 2 days data + periodically ( interval of 10 mins ) checking for updates with ajax from this table ...

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Is there an Index on "created_date" in the table?

Comment: currently I am  using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in created_date field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place index in created_date field. It will boost performance a lot...

Links:
MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html
Using SQLyog: http://www.weberdev.com/ViewArticle/Managing-Foreign-Key-Relationships-In-MySQL-Using-SQLyog
WIKI: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/primary_key

Comment: can you please explain .. how to create a index ?

Answer (score 2):

You should add an index on "created_date" if not yet.
more over you can use "explain" to optimize your query. here is some easy ways to [optimize queries](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/three-easy-ways-to-optimize-your-mysql-queries/6137168).